# trying to call a variable from a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

what i want t do is to call `port.getferry.getname()`;but when i try to compile its shows me

> "cannot find symbol  k=port.getferry.getname();
>
> symbol: variable getferry
>
> location:class Port"

i just dont know what to do i try to change the variable from private to protected or public but nothing change this is a small piece of my program so  i dont give you a compliced programm ,

```
class tp{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Port[] port=new Port[1];
        String k,limenas;
        Ferry[] ferry=new Ferry[1];
        String name=UserInput.getString();
        ferry[1]=new Ferry(name);
        port[1]=new Port(limenas,ferry[1]);
        k=port[1].getferry.getname();
  }

}

class Port{
    private String limenas;
    public Ferry ferry;
    Port(String li,Ferry ferry){
        limenas=li;
        this.ferry=ferry;
    }
    public String getlimenas(){
        return limenas;
    }
    public Ferry getferry(){
        return ferry;
    }
}

class Ferry extends Vessel{
    Ferry(String name){
        super(name);
    }
}

class Vessel{
    private String name;
    Vessel(String n){
         name=n;
    }
    public String getname(){
         return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: try port.getferry().getname()

Comment: in my main program i have an array of Port, will this work again there ?

Comment: Class inheritance is a big PITA. Avoid as much as possible. Read "Design Patterns" by Gamma et al for alternatives.

Comment: Class inheritance is an important facet to OOP, however, and you should at least understand how it works

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to call a method without parenthesis.

```
port.getferry();  //will return a ferry object.  

ferry.getname();  //will return the name of the ferry object.
```

To chain them, you should try:

```
port.getferry().getname();
```

this will return a ferry object and get the name from it, returning a string.

this will also work if you have an array of port objects, you could call

```
port[1].getferry().getname()
```

and it would get the ferry at the port in array reference 1, as above, provided port is the name of your port array.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you are going to run into a problem with your arrays.

Java arrays begin at 0

Port[] port=new Port[1]; // array of length 1

k=port[1]... would get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception

port[0] is valid, port[1] is not.